# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

En Windows10, tengo instalado Anaconda3 5.0.1. Este paquete parece que no incluye **pandas-datareader**. 
He comprobado, ejecutando el mismo script en Linux con la misma versión de Anaconda3 e instalando este paquete, que el script funciona correctamente. He buscado en internet y no acabo de saber cómo instalar este paquete en Windows10.

He probado abriendo el símbolo del sistema y escribiendo: conda install pandas-datareader
Obtengo el error:  ""conda" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable".
He realizado la misma prueba pero dentro del directorio Anaconda3. El resultado ha sido el mismo

Comment: No tienes conda agregado al path (no se agrega por defecto si no lo indicas en la instalación de Anaconda). Deberías tener Anaconda Command Prompt en tu menú inicio (busca “Anaconda”). Luego puedes instalar vía `conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader`.

Comment: En la instalación de Anaconda3 no me pidió nada. He optado por  sustituirlo por  Miniconda. Ya me aparece Anaconda Command Prompt en el menú de inicio y me acepta comandos con Conda. Iré añadiendo paquetes a medida que los vaya necesitando.

Comment: En otro ordenador he instalado la última versión descargada de Anaconda3, identificado el Anaconda Command  Prompt y comprobado que tu opción funciona.